# Messages shows my Status "offline"

Tags: high-sierra, messages

I have Messages on my MacBook Pro running 10.13.3 and have received the odd message from my daughter.

I tried to use to send and the icon in the Dock shows my Status "offline" and I can't seem to change this even if I select "Available"

Comment: I always thought the 'online status' stuff was for other messaging systems, not 'iMessage' itself.

Comment: @Tetsujin Agree, what would be 'offline' for Messages?  I'm rarely at my mac and my family never sees anything related to my status being online or offline.